# Number correcting

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im writing code with a part that is confusing me.

```
while answer1 != 'a':
    if answer1 == 'b':
        print('\nWrong answer.\n')
    answer1= input("\nEnter again.\nYou only have one more try!\n")
    amount = amount+1
    print(amount)#for testing
    if amount == 1:
        print("\nTry next question")
    break
```

What I want to do is to have the tries to be two if the user said 'b' twice. I have put amount as 1 but if the user says a, then it will be two. What I want to do is to have the tries to two if 'b' is said twice but one if 'a' is said once.

Comment: Indentation is very important in python, please format your code.

Comment: No, I didn't see that it was not indented when I was writing the question.

Comment: will it be `bb` or just `b` on two different instances, it is difficult to understand expected behavior with just this snippet

Answer (score 0):

So, the overall goal here is unclear. However, I think this may help you out:

First of all, drop the `while answer != 'a'`, and go to `while True`, rely on the conditional inside the loop to handle `break` / `continue`.

```py
amount = 1 # Initiate amount outside of the loop, otherwise it'll get reset on each loop.
while True: # Run until base condition is met.
    print("I am the question")
    ANSWER = input("Answer: ")
    if ANSWER == 'a' or amount >= 2: # Base condition.
        print(amount)
        break 
    else: # This runs if answer isn't what you want.
        print("Wrong, please try again.")
        amount += 1
        continue
```

Best